# Enhancing Perl regular expression for balanced matching

Tags: regex, perl

I am routinely using the following regex for balanced matching

```
my $np;
$np = qr{
                \{
                (?:
                        (?> [^\{\}]+ )
                    |
                        (??{ $np })
                )*
                \}
            }x;
```

as, for example,

```
my $text = "{string{string1}{string2}}";
$text =~ /($np)/;
```

The question is whether it can be extended such that it matches also when `string` etc. contains a `}` or `{` preceded by a backslash. This means that escaped curly brackets should be ignored (treated like any other character) when the balanced matching is performed.

Comment: @M42: The referenced question is a general one about matching balanced pairs of brackets. It doesn't help this poster, who already knows how to do that but can't match *escaped* braces as regular text between the matched ones.

Comment: Are you really using `NSRegularExpression`? In which case this isn't Perl at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. All you have to do is change the *"any other character"* expression to one that will accept escaped braces as well as *"anything except a brace"*

```
(?>  (?: \\[()] | [^{}] )+  )
```

Note also that the `(??{ $np })` construct has long been superseded, and if you have version 10 or later of Perl 5 you can use the built-in *recursion* mechanism, whereby `(?R)` will recurse the entire expression from the start.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $np = qr{
  \{
    (?:
      (?>
        (?: \\\\ | \\} | \\} | [^{}] )*
      )
    |
      (?R)
    )*
  \}
}xs; 

my $text = '{string{string1 \} test}{string2}}';
$text =~ /($np)/;

say $1;
```

**output**

```
{string{string1 \} test}{string2}}
```

Please note that I don't believe the *"no backtrack"* construct `(?> ... )` is useful here. The intermediate string has been specified so that anything following *must* match the next token or the end of the string, and there are no non-greedy wildcards. But I am sure it does no harm so I have left it in.

---

**Update**

To allow for escaped opening braces *before* the first regular brace, it is simplest to write a separate regex for a *"regular character"*, which is anything but an opening or closing brace, or an escaped anything.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $reg_char = qr/(?: \\. | [^{}] )/xs;  # Define what *isn't* a brace

my $np = qr{
  \{
    (?:
      (?> $reg_char* )
    |
      (?R)
    )*
  \}
}x; 

my $text = 'aaa \{ bbb {string{string1 \} test}{string2}}';
die unless $text =~ / $reg_char* ($np) /x;

say $1;
```

**output**

```
{string{string1 \} test}{string2}}
```

Comment: Not explicitly mentioned in the question, but you probably also need to check that the opening brace is not escaped.  Also, a double backslash before a brace is probably an escaped backslash and should not escape the brace...

Comment: Yes exactly, but I figured that I can do this with a negative lookbehind `(?<!\\)` in front of `\}`... That correct? Double backslashes not, I think.

Comment: @highsciguy: If you're expecting escaped open braces *outside* any bracketed text then I think the negative look-behind is the simplest choice. Otherwise you would have to add the *"regular character"* expression before the opening brace. I've added escaped backslash as one of the regular chartacters that will be skipped, as it won't do any harm.

Comment: I think you are right. What would the "regular character" expression look like?

Comment: @highsciguy: I've written it: take a look at my solution. It's just a matter of extracting that part of the existing regex and defining it separately.